# HTML in bootstrap tooltip

Tags: angular, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I am working on Angular 2 project and I use bootstrap tooltip. I have project name fetched by API. I want to display this project names in tooltip when one hovers over a component. Is it possible to add this data in html?

Answer (score 1):

Add `data-toggle="tooltip"` to add tooltip on hover of your component. You might need to initialize it using `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` in your `.ts` file.

```
<app-differen-component data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip content">

</app-differen-component>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But my question is how can I add html in its title property? I tried by using data-html = true and tried adding html directly in title. But it gives error, because it is not possible in Angular

Answer (score 0):

You could use a third-party library like https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples:

```
<p>
  Tooltips can contain any arbitrary HTML, Angular bindings and even directives!
  Simply enclose desired content in a <code>&lt;ng-template&gt;</code> element.
</p>

<ng-template #tipContent>Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>!</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent">
  I've got markup and bindings in my tooltip!
</button>
```

Comment: I can use it but in my project there are some collapsible headers. In ng-bootstrap they didn't add animations yet. And if I would use both bootstrap and ng-bootstrap it might be possible that some of the funtions don't work properly